# dynamic upload field arguments

Tags: django, django-models

if I have basic model for keeping track of client art:

```
class ArtEntry(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
    job_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    descriptor = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    post_type = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=POST_CHOICES)
```

and the last field of this model is a file upload field:

```
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/*/**/***')
```

is it possible to populate the "upload_to" argument dynamically, so that * = the input 'client' data and ** = the input 'job_number' and *** = the 'post_type' choice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [USe dynamic destination folder for uploaded file in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936614/use-dynamic-destination-folder-for-uploaded-file-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Just check the docs for [`upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

> This may also be a callable, such as a function, which will be called
>   to obtain the upload path, including the filename.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1190866/630877) to see an example which you can easily adapt to your problem.

Comment: The example was EXACTLY what I needed. Configured and tested. I'm a happy camper. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

One Example;

```
def image_path(self, uploaded_file_name):
    prefix = 'documents/'
    extension = os.path.splitext(uploaded_file_name)[-1]
    if self.pk != None:
        return prefix + str(self.pk) + extension
    else:
        tmp_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.temp_image = prefix + tmp_name + extension
        return self.temp_image

image_upload = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_path, null=True, blank=True)
```

You should use python functions.